# How to write a boundHelper to iterate a map in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a model which contains an [Ember.Map](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Map.html), and I want to render the content of that map in a template.

I've tried using the custom bound helper below, but the template will not re-render as values are added/removed from the map.

Essentially I just want to replicate the behaviour of `{{#each}}` for a map.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('eachInMap', function(map, block) {
  out = "";
  map.forEach(function(k,v) {
    out += block.fn(v)
  });
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(out);
}, /* what dependencies to put here? */);
```

Invoked by a template

```
{{#eachInMap myMap}} foo bar {{/eachInMap}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/2659.
Basically, boundHelpers don't currently support blocks sorry.

The current workaround is to create a non-bound helper and wrap it in a `{{#bind}}` block.